# Проблема с установкой пакетов в Python

Tags: python, pip

Не могу установить ни через консоль пайчарма, ни через командную строку необходимые пакеты.
Выдает следующее

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not 
writeable
Collecting discord
Using cached discord-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 kB)
Collecting discord.py>=2.1.0
Using cached discord.py-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4
Using cached aiohttp-3.8.3.tar.gz (7.3 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5
   Using cached multidict-6.0.2.tar.gz (50 kB)
   Installing build dependencies ... done
   Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0
   Using cached attrs-22.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting frozenlist>=1.1.1
   Using cached frozenlist-1.3.3.tar.gz (66 kB)
   Installing build dependencies ... done
   Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting aiosignal>=1.1.2
   Using cached aiosignal-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3.0,>=2.0 in 
c:\users\макс\.local\lib\python3.8\site-packages (from 
aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py>=2.1.0->discord) (2.0.12)
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0
   Using cached yarl-1.8.1.tar.gz (172 kB)
   Installing build dependencies ... done
   Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting async-timeout<5.0,>=4.0.0a3
   Using cached async_timeout-4.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in 
c:\users\макс\.local\lib\python3.8\site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py>=2.1.0->discord) (3.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: aiohttp, frozenlist, multidict, yarl
Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [94 lines of output]
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.mingw-cpython-38
  creating build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\abc.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\base_protocol.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\client.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\client_exceptions.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\client_proto.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\client_reqrep.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\client_ws.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\connector.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\cookiejar.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\formdata.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\hdrs.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\helpers.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\http.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\http_exceptions.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\http_parser.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\http_websocket.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\http_writer.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\locks.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\log.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\multipart.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\payload.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\payload_streamer.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\pytest_plugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\resolver.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\streams.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\tcp_helpers.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\test_utils.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\tracing.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\typedefs.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\web.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\web_app.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\web_exceptions.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\web_fileresponse.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\web_log.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\web_middlewares.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\web_protocol.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\web_request.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\web_response.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\web_routedef.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\web_runner.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\web_server.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\web_ws.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\worker.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  running egg_info
  writing aiohttp.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to aiohttp.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to aiohttp.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to aiohttp.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  *********************
  * Accelerated build *
  *********************
  warning: no files found matching 'aiohttp' anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'aiohttp\*.html'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
  writing manifest file 'aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying aiohttp\_cparser.pxd -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\_find_header.pxd -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\_headers.pxi -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\_helpers.pyi -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\_helpers.pyx -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\_http_parser.pyx -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\_http_writer.pyx -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\_websocket.pyx -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  copying aiohttp\py.typed -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp
  creating build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp\.hash
  copying aiohttp\.hash\_cparser.pxd.hash -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp\.hash
  copying aiohttp\.hash\_find_header.pxd.hash -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp\.hash
  copying aiohttp\.hash\_helpers.pyi.hash -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp\.hash
  copying aiohttp\.hash\_helpers.pyx.hash -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp\.hash
  copying aiohttp\.hash\_http_parser.pyx.hash -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp\.hash
  copying aiohttp\.hash\_http_writer.pyx.hash -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp\.hash
  copying aiohttp\.hash\_websocket.pyx.hash -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp\.hash
  copying aiohttp\.hash\hdrs.py.hash -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\aiohttp\.hash
  running build_ext
  building 'aiohttp._websocket' extension
  error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
  Building wheel for frozenlist (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

 × Building wheel for frozenlist (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [33 lines of output]
  *********************
  * Accelerated build *
  *********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.mingw-cpython-38
  creating build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\frozenlist
  copying frozenlist\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\frozenlist
  running egg_info
  writing frozenlist.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to frozenlist.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to frozenlist.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'frozenlist.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'frozenlist\*.html'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  adding license file 'LICENSE'
  writing manifest file 'frozenlist.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying frozenlist\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\frozenlist
  copying frozenlist\_frozenlist.pyx -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\frozenlist
  copying frozenlist\py.typed -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\frozenlist
  running build_ext
  building 'frozenlist._frozenlist' extension
  error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
  [end of output]

 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for frozenlist
 Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml) ... error
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [59 lines of output]
  *********************
  * Accelerated build *
  *********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.mingw-cpython-38
  creating build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\multidict
  copying multidict\_abc.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\multidict
  copying multidict\_compat.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict_base.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict_py.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\multidict
  copying multidict\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\multidict
  running egg_info
  writing multidict.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to multidict.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to multidict.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\_multidict.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  adding license file 'LICENSE'
  writing manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying multidict\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\multidict
  copying multidict\py.typed -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\multidict
  running build_ext
  building 'multidict._multidict' extension
  C:\Users\Макс\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-l66no6je\overlay\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:202: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning:     Installing 'multidict._multilib' as data is deprecated, please list it in `packages`.
      !!


      ############################
      # Package would be ignored #
      ############################
      Python recognizes 'multidict._multilib' as an importable package,
      but it is not listed in the `packages` configuration of setuptools.

      'multidict._multilib' has been automatically added to the distribution only
      because it may contain data files, but this behavior is likely to change
      in future versions of setuptools (and therefore is considered deprecated).

      Please make sure that 'multidict._multilib' is included as a package by using
      the `packages` configuration field or the proper discovery methods
      (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
      instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

      You can read more about "package discovery" and "data files" on setuptools
      documentation page.


  !!

    check.warn(importable)
  error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
Building wheel for yarl (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for yarl (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [37 lines of output]
  **********************
  * Accelerated build *
  **********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.mingw-cpython-38
  creating build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_py.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\yarl
  copying yarl\_url.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\yarl
  copying yarl\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\yarl
  running egg_info
  writing yarl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to yarl.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  C:\Users\Макс\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u26zvwq0\overlay\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
    warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  adding license file 'LICENSE'
  writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying yarl\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyi -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyx -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\yarl
  copying yarl\py.typed -> build\lib.mingw-cpython-38\yarl
  running build_ext
  building 'yarl._quoting_c' extension
  error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build aiohttp frozenlist multidict yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, frozenlist, multidict, yarl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Сколько не пытался найти ответ, так и не смог решить данную проблему, удалял все пакеты и IDE связанные с Пайтоном и все переустанавливал, тоже не помогло...

Comment: Извиняюсь, за скриншоты с терминала, вставил ошибку что выдается при установке.

Comment: Не знаю, в чем может быть дело, но есть одна странность, похоже у Вас домашний каталог кириллицей, это не может ошибку давать?

Comment: Какая версия Python?

Answer (score 0):

*уточнение, питоном в виндах не пользуюсь*

1. если устанавливаете от администратора root проблем быть не должно.
2. если от пользователя, то система не даст вам сделать изменения, что и видим в первой же строке "normal site-packages is **not writeable**". вам следует устанавливать с ключом --user

прим., еще бывают варианты что установил в личный каталог питон-модули **администратором**. и потом пользователем невозможно установить. тут надо удалять от root-а сначала.

3. еще допустимо и рекомендуемо использовать виртуальные питоны. напр., **venv** со своими расположениями модулей

Comment: Run CMD as an administrator                       https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-defaulting-to-user-installation-because-normal-site-packages-is-not-writable